# How to delete text from variable after matching some pattern?

Tags: shell-script, string

I wish to delete some text before some pattern. For example:

```
VAR="This is a test script text and real script text."
PATTERN="test "
```

And the desired output that I want is:

```
NEW_VAR="script text and real script text."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a shell that supports parameter expansions of type `${WORD##*STR}`, then all you need to do is below.

```
printf '%s\n' "${VAR##*$PATTERN}"
```

To store it in the new variable, use the command substitution trick with `$(..)` or use `printf`'s inherent capability to store the formatted string in a new variable

```
printf -v NEW_VAR '%s' "${VAR##*$PATTERN}"
printf '%s\n' "$NEW_VAR"
```

Using the shell to do the substitution is a bit effective that forking an external utility like `sed` or `awk`.

Quoting from [Parameter Expansion Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

> `${PARAMETER##PATTERN}`
>
> This form is to remove the described pattern trying to match it from the **beginning of the string**. The operator `##` will try to remove the longest text matching.

Comment: Hi, your answer worked flawlessly. Can you briefly explain more on the code?

Answer (score 0):

No `printf` needed - assign new variable using "parameter expansion:

```
NEW=${VAR#*$PATTERN}
echo $NEW
script text and real script text.
```